# Finish faster CSS Animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an hourglass CSS element with CSS keyframe animation. Animation works for infinite time; at the end of each iteration, it rotates to the start position and continues working.

I need to restart the animation on the button click. But not to restart immediately, but to speed it up very fast to start position and after that to start working normally again.

I tried on click to change the style for animation-duration I iteration count, but then the animation stop immediately. And on-end animation event to put it to work normally, but it starts from the last position.

```js
const hourglass = document.querySelector(".hourglass")
const before = document.querySelector(".before")
const after = document.querySelector(".after")

const button = document.querySelector('button');

const handleClick = ()=>{
    hourglass.style.animationDuration = '1s';
  hourglass.style.animationIterationCount = 1
  
    before.style.animationDuration = '1s';
  before.style.animationIterationCount = 1
  
    after.style.animationDuration = '1s';
  after.style.animationIterationCount = 1
}

button.addEventListener('click',handleClick);

  hourglass.addEventListener('animationend', (event) => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        hourglass.style.animationDuration = '8s';
  hourglass.style.animationIterationCount = "infinite";
  
    before.style.animationDuration = '8s';
  before.style.animationIterationCount = "infinite";
  
    after.style.animationDuration = '8s';
  after.style.animationIterationCount = "infinite";
    },1000)
    
  });
```

```css
*
{
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
:root
{
  --bg:#e3e4e8;
  --fg:#2e3138;
  --primary:#255ff4;
  font-size: calc(16px + (24 - 16) *(100vw - 320px) / (1280 - 320));
}
body
{
  display: grid;
  font:1em/1.5 sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  place-items:center;
}
.hourglass, .hourglass .before, .hourglass .after
{
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
}

.hourglass {
  --polygonH: polygon(0% 0%,100% 0%,100% 5.55%,95% 5.55%,95% 28%,60%
   46%,60% 54%,95% 72%,95% 94.45%,100% 94.45%,100% 100%,0% 100%,0% 94.45%,5% 94.45%,5% 72%,40% 54%,40% 46%,5% 28%,5% 5.55%,0% 5.55%);
  animation-name: flip;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  background-image: linear-gradient(var(--primary) 0.5em, #737a8c55 0.5em 8.5em, var(--primary) 8.5em);
  clip-path: var(--polygonH);
  -webkit-clip-path: var(--polygonH);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 5em;
  height: 9em;
  z-index: 0;
}
.hourglass .before, .hourglass .after
{
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
.hourglass .before {
  --polygonB1: polygon(0% 0%,100% 0%,100% 24%,50% 47%,50% 47%,50% 47%,50% 47%,50% 47%,50% 47%,50% 47%,50% 47%,0% 24%);
  --polygonB2: polygon(0% 4%,100% 4%,100% 24%,55% 45%,55% 100%,55% 100%,55% 100%,45% 100%,45% 100%,45% 100%,45% 45%,0% 24%);
  --polygonB3: polygon(0% 24%,100% 24%,100% 24%,55% 45%,55% 80%,100% 100%,100% 100%,0% 100%,0% 100%,45% 80%,45% 45%,0% 24%);
  --polygonB4: polygon(45% 45%,55% 45%,55% 45%,55% 45%,55% 58%,100% 76%,100% 100%,0% 100%,0% 76%,45% 58%,45% 45%,45% 45%);
  --polygonB5: polygon(50% 53%,50% 53%,50% 53%,50% 53%,50% 53%,100% 76%,100% 100%,0% 100%,0% 76%,50% 53%,50% 53%,50% 53%);
  animation-name: fill;
  background: var(--fg);
  background-size: 100% 3.6em;
  clip-path: var(--polygonB1);
  top: 0.5em;
  left: 0.5em;
  width: 4em;
  height: 8em;
  z-index: 1;
}
.hourglass .after {
  animation-name: glare;
  background:
    linear-gradient(90deg,#0000 0.5em,#0003 0.5em 1.5em,#0000 1.5em 3.5em,#fff3 3.5em 4.5em,#fff0 4.5em 6.5em,#0003 6.5em 7.5em,#0000 7.5em) 0 0 / 100% 0.5em,
    linear-gradient(90deg,#0000 0.75em,#0003 0.75em 1.25em,#0000 1.25em 3.75em,#fff3 3.75em 4.25em,#fff0 4.25em 6.75em,#0003 6.75em 7.25em,#0000 7.25em) 0 0.5em / 100% 8em,
    linear-gradient(90deg,#0000 0.5em,#0003 0.5em 1.5em,#0000 1.5em 3.5em,#fff3 3.5em 4.5em,#fff0 4.5em 6.5em,#0003 6.5em 7.5em,#0000 7.5em) 0 100% / 100% 0.5em;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    top: 0;
    left: -3em;
    width: 200%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  @keyframes fill{
    from{
      clip-path: var(--polygonB1);
      -webkit-clip-path:var(--polygonB1);
    }
    10%{
      clip-path: var(--polygonB2);
      -webkit-clip-path:var(--polygonB2);
    }
    45%{
      clip-path: var(--polygonB3);
      -webkit-clip-path:var(--polygonB3);
    }
    80%{
      clip-path: var(--polygonB4);
      -webkit-clip-path:var(--polygonB4);
    }
    85%, to{
      clip-path: var(--polygonB5);
      -webkit-clip-path:var(--polygonB5);
    }
  }
  @keyframes glare{
    from, 90%
    {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
    to
    {
      transform: translateX(3em);
    }
  }
  @keyframes flip{
    from, 90%
    {
      transform: rotate(0);
    }
    to{
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
  }
  
  
  button{
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
  }
```

```html
<div class="hourglass">
  <div class="before"></div>
  <div class="after"></div>
</div>

<button >Click</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution problem is that when you change the duration of animations if the rest time is lower than your new duration it will immediately be stopped. So I activate and remove animation and started it in javascript and take time when it started. We don't need to do that on the initial, because we can use event listener oneventstart, but on every other iteration, we will need to do that, so I just reuse that piece of code instead create a new one.

On click, I take the time of that moment and compare it with the start time. That time means how long that animation working until that moment. Add to that 250ms and the animation will be finished in that time.

After that, we need to reset the animation again, so it will start from the beginning instead of an old position.

```js
const hourglass = document.querySelector(".hourglass");
const before = document.querySelector(".before");
const after = document.querySelector(".after");

const button = document.querySelector("button");

// Initial
const resetAnimation = () => {
  hourglass.style.animationName = "none";
  before.style.animationName = "none";
  after.style.animationName = "none";
};

resetAnimation();

let time;
let disableClick = false;

const activeAnimation = () => {
  disableClick = false;

  const speed = "8000ms";
  time = +new Date();

  hourglass.style.animationName = "";
  before.style.animationName = "";
  after.style.animationName = "";

  hourglass.style.animationDuration = speed;
  before.style.animationDuration = speed;
  after.style.animationDuration = speed;
};

activeAnimation();

const handleClick = () => {
  if (disableClick) return;

  disableClick = true;

  const newTime = +new Date();

  const speed = newTime - time + 250;

  hourglass.style.animationDuration = speed + "ms";
  before.style.animationDuration = speed + "ms";
  after.style.animationDuration = speed + "ms";
};

button.addEventListener("click", handleClick);

hourglass.addEventListener("animationiteration", (event) => {
  resetAnimation();

  setTimeout(() => {
    activeAnimation();
  }, 100);
});
```

```css
* {
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
:root {
  --bg: #e3e4e8;
  --fg: #2e3138;
  --primary: #255ff4;
  font-size: calc(16px + (24 - 16) * (100vw - 320px) / (1280 - 320));
}
body {
  display: grid;
  font: 1em/1.5 sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  place-items: center;
}
.hourglass,
.hourglass .before,
.hourglass .after {
  animation-duration: 8000ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.hourglass {
  --polygonH: polygon(
    0% 0%,
    100% 0%,
    100% 5.55%,
    95% 5.55%,
    95% 28%,
    60% 46%,
    60% 54%,
    95% 72%,
    95% 94.45%,
    100% 94.45%,
    100% 100%,
    0% 100%,
    0% 94.45%,
    5% 94.45%,
    5% 72%,
    40% 54%,
    40% 46%,
    5% 28%,
    5% 5.55%,
    0% 5.55%
  );
  animation-name: flip;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    var(--primary) 0.5em,
    #737a8c55 0.5em 8.5em,
    var(--primary) 8.5em
  );
  clip-path: var(--polygonH);
  -webkit-clip-path: var(--polygonH);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 5em;
  height: 9em;
  z-index: 0;
}
.hourglass .before,
.hourglass .after {
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
.hourglass .before {
  --polygonB1: polygon(
    0% 0%,
    100% 0%,
    100% 24%,
    50% 47%,
    50% 47%,
    50% 47%,
    50% 47%,
    50% 47%,
    50% 47%,
    50% 47%,
    50% 47%,
    0% 24%
  );
  --polygonB2: polygon(
    0% 4%,
    100% 4%,
    100% 24%,
    55% 45%,
    55% 100%,
    55% 100%,
    55% 100%,
    45% 100%,
    45% 100%,
    45% 100%,
    45% 45%,
    0% 24%
  );
  --polygonB3: polygon(
    0% 24%,
    100% 24%,
    100% 24%,
    55% 45%,
    55% 80%,
    100% 100%,
    100% 100%,
    0% 100%,
    0% 100%,
    45% 80%,
    45% 45%,
    0% 24%
  );
  --polygonB4: polygon(
    45% 45%,
    55% 45%,
    55% 45%,
    55% 45%,
    55% 58%,
    100% 76%,
    100% 100%,
    0% 100%,
    0% 76%,
    45% 58%,
    45% 45%,
    45% 45%
  );
  --polygonB5: polygon(
    50% 53%,
    50% 53%,
    50% 53%,
    50% 53%,
    50% 53%,
    100% 76%,
    100% 100%,
    0% 100%,
    0% 76%,
    50% 53%,
    50% 53%,
    50% 53%
  );
  animation-name: fill;
  background: var(--fg);
  background-size: 100% 3.6em;
  clip-path: var(--polygonB1);
  top: 0.5em;
  left: 0.5em;
  width: 4em;
  height: 8em;
  z-index: 1;
}
.hourglass .after {
  animation-name: glare;
  background: linear-gradient(
        90deg,
        #0000 0.5em,
        #0003 0.5em 1.5em,
        #0000 1.5em 3.5em,
        #fff3 3.5em 4.5em,
        #fff0 4.5em 6.5em,
        #0003 6.5em 7.5em,
        #0000 7.5em
      )
      0 0 / 100% 0.5em,
    linear-gradient(
        90deg,
        #0000 0.75em,
        #0003 0.75em 1.25em,
        #0000 1.25em 3.75em,
        #fff3 3.75em 4.25em,
        #fff0 4.25em 6.75em,
        #0003 6.75em 7.25em,
        #0000 7.25em
      )
      0 0.5em / 100% 8em,
    linear-gradient(
        90deg,
        #0000 0.5em,
        #0003 0.5em 1.5em,
        #0000 1.5em 3.5em,
        #fff3 3.5em 4.5em,
        #fff0 4.5em 6.5em,
        #0003 6.5em 7.5em,
        #0000 7.5em
      )
      0 100% / 100% 0.5em;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  top: 0;
  left: -3em;
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
@keyframes fill {
  from {
    clip-path: var(--polygonB1);
    -webkit-clip-path: var(--polygonB1);
  }
  10% {
    clip-path: var(--polygonB2);
    -webkit-clip-path: var(--polygonB2);
  }
  45% {
    clip-path: var(--polygonB3);
    -webkit-clip-path: var(--polygonB3);
  }
  80% {
    clip-path: var(--polygonB4);
    -webkit-clip-path: var(--polygonB4);
  }
  85%,
  to {
    clip-path: var(--polygonB5);
    -webkit-clip-path: var(--polygonB5);
  }
}
@keyframes glare {
  from,
  90% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(3em);
  }
}
@keyframes flip {
  from,
  90% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

button {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="hourglass">
      <div class="before"></div>
      <div class="after"></div>
    </div>

    <button>Click</button>
```

Comment: Yes this is it. I see you set some disable variable for button. Can you explain that? Thank you.

Comment: Disable button is because I want to prevent users to click it multiple times until the full iteration will be done. We have some timeout events, and if you click it multiple times it will be broke a little. We can clear time out or something like that. But this solution doesn't require that.